# dry humor or "deadpan"

Tags: переводы

Как перевести на Русский "dry humor", "dry sense of humor" или "deadpan"?

Comment: Спросите на англоязычном ресурсе. http://russian.stackexchange.com/ Здесь народ в массе не искушен в переводах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое, что приходит в голову, конечно, это «тонкий английский юмор», но сами англичане ведь не называют *весь* свой юмор сухим.

Вот что я нашла [здесь](http://iloveenglish.ru/stories/view/tymannij_anglijskij_yumor_v_detalyakh):

> Кроме того, можно еще выделить *иронию* или «сухое» чувство юмора (dry sense of humour).

(курсив мой)

Вот возможные варианты перевода, в зависимости от контекста:

- ирония
- сарказм
- свойственная англичанам ирония
- свойственная англичанам самоирония

Еще ([отсюда](http://mgimo.ru/upload/iblock/6e1/6e1a977e1386ba2cfd36d9ca3e5b5bcc.pdf))

> dry humour – ироничные шутки, в которых под маской серьёзности скрывается 
>   насмешка. Например, студентка просит профессора отпустить её с лекции, на что 
>   он свершено серьёзно отвечает: 
>   I am sure it’ll break  my heart, 
>   but you may leave. 
>   (Я уверен, это разобьёт мне сердце, но вы можете идти.)

Comment: Насчёт маски серьёзности, это просто общечеловеческое правило: когда шутите, не ржите громко первым. Наверно англичанам это даётся легче чем другим :)

Answer (score 2):

Буквальный перевод из гугла так и будет - "сухой юмор". Но мне кажется, что dry humor и deadpan означают как раз отсутствие какого-либо юмора. Humor-less.
Dry sense of humor - это "сухой юмор", есть ещё такое слово, как "чопорность". И есть выражение "тонкий английский юмор" (см. анекдоты про старого лорда и дворецкого, и т. д.).
Вообще humor имеет два значения - это манера/стиль общения/поведения в целом, и юмор - в смысле нечто смешное, забавное.

Comment: Я спрашивал о литературном переводе.  "Dry humor" больше всего характеризуеца тем что не всегда понятно это шутка или сказано в серьез.  Может быть "тонкий юмор"?

Comment: Нет, я не могу перевести "dry humor" как "тонкий юмор". Скорее как чопорный стиль поведения/выражения. Если бы "dry SENSE of humor" то с большой натяжкой можно "тонкое чувство юмора", но более подошло бы "своеобразное чувство юмора".  Тяжёлый вопрос Вы задали.

Comment: Возможно это зависит от личного отношения к такому юмору.  Тому кому такие шутки лично не нравятся могли бы его назвать безюморным.  Но "тонкий юмор" тоже может использоватьца как back-handed compliment юмориста  --  то есть "слишком тонкий" или "заумный".  Мне кажетьса пересечение у двух понятий большое.  Но точный перевод не обязательно есть.

Comment: Я пытался ответить именно в контексте литературного перевода, а не личного отношения. ИМХО "сухой" и "тонкий" юмор сильно различаются по смыслу.

Answer (score 2):

Юмор, когда непонятно юмор ли это вообще называется "английским". Образцом подобного юмора можно считать некоторые миниатюры "Монти Пайтон".

Comment: А как перевести-то исходное?

Comment: Ответа не получил, поэтому комментирую. Это не совсем ответ на вопрос, но мысль верная. Поэтому - +))))

Comment: @behemothus я плохо владею английским, поэтому при ответ опирался не на сам вопрос, а на комментарий автора, описывающий данный юмор. По-русски его называют "английским", что я и написал в своём ответе.

Comment: Я ничего против не имею. Хотел уточнить просто.

Answer (score 2):

Какими словами перевести (а буквальный перевод идиом бесполезен), зависит от контекста, с которым требуется это понятие согласовать. Здесь достаточно хорошо растолковано, что это такое:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpan

По смыслу это высказывание, в котором заложена **скрытая ирония**, и форма донесения которого (с невозмутимым видом; deadpan примерно соответствует нашему "**с каменным лицом**") не позволяет определить, видит ли сам говорящий эту иронию, "долю шутки". Ирония может не полностью заключаться в самом высказывании (её распознание может оказаться возможным только в рамках текущей ситуации и т.д.). Как разновидность остроты, это используется и в комических шоу. И это не чисто английское явление, как можно заключить из примеров, приводимых в сети.

> Журналист: Каковы по вашему, уроки Французской революции?
>
> Мао Цзе Дун: Ответ на этот вопрос был бы преждевременным.
>
> Журналист: Что вы думаете о Западной цивилизации?
>
> М. Ганди: Было бы интересно на таковую посмотреть!

Из моих примеров:

(телеинтервью на BBC)

> Келли Осборн: Как ты относишься к Элису Куперу?
>
> Эми Уайнхаус (не задумываясь): Я думаю, она великолепна!

(обычно Alice - женское имя, и невозможно было определить, знает Эми знаменитого музыканта или делает вид, что в курсе всех жанров)

Ну и классическое высказывание В. Черномырдина я бы сюда отнёс (не знаю, пытался ли он пошутить в тот момент):

> - Хотели как лучше, а получилось как всегда.

Comment: Меня тоже удивило название "Англиский юмор", так как он не исключительно Британский.  Но из всех приведеных ссылок похоже что эта  фраза в обиходе.

Comment: В каких-то случаях это может подойти - возможно, по отношению к неангличанину, по аналогии с "прощанием по-английски", которое англичане называют "по-французски" :)

Answer (score 2):

Одно из значений dry - рафинированный, очищенный. 
Здесь вполне подходит, именно такой смысл и вкладывают англичане.
Ну а конкретный вариант перевода надо смотреть по контексту.

Deadpan - тут не знаю, это уже реальная идиома, тут перевести сложно, не нарушив образность.
А хотя, нет. Вот есть нечто близкое: "Деревянное (или каменное) лицо".